# SPFx Loading Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, 2019, spfx-extensions

I have created the SPFx Project with extension and Web parts. It is working well if I run `gulp serve`. If I refresh the browser page it is not loading.

It throws an error. If I copy the same URL without any changes in code/URL to the new tab of the page app working well for the first time.

Error:

> "Custom action component ids are specified by query parameters but matching manifests cannot be found. Ids: a39bcc81-468a-46f7-8abe-862f6ade621e".

Browsers that I Checked:

- Chrome
- Edge
- IE
- Firefox

All above mentioned browsers are throwing an error for the second time, if page refresh. This problem occurs after the development of `ListViewCommandSet` extension (separate project).

Also, developer tool does not load the webpack folder for second time.
I have also unstall browser and re-installed it(Chrome).But no luck.

Can any one help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently looks to be a bug from Microsoft end. Multiple bugs have been logged for this issue. Here's one thread, that I'm following: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5385

Meanwhile, as an alternative, you can add the below line in your `onInit()`.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("spfx-debug", "");
```

Comment: @Mohammed Rayan - Thanks for your help!!.